# Why does this code works on one platform but doesn't work on another?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, boost, visual-studio-2019, centos8

I've written a long and complicated server program on windows. Used visual studio 2019.

Then I've created a CentOS 8 operating system on vm virtualbox and transferred all the code there. And rebuilt an executable with visual code. That works okay except one part.

Here is the code that causes the crash:

```
//clients is    std::map<int, boost::shared_ptr<Client>> clients;

        for (const auto& kv : clients) {
            
            int elapsed_seconds = boost::chrono::duration_cast<boost::chrono::seconds>(timeNow - kv.second->lastUpdated).count();

            int i = kv.first;

            if (elapsed_seconds >= ServerData::SessionTimeoutSeconds)
            {
                trash_bin.push_back(clients[i]);
                clients.erase(i);
            }
        }
```

this works without any bug on windows(compiled with visual studio 2019)

but gives this error on centos 8 (compiled with visual code / g++)

> Assertion `px != 0' failed. Aborted (core dumped)

But if I put break; right after client.erase(i); problem is solved.

```
if (elapsed_seconds >= ServerData::SessionTimeoutSeconds)
{
    trash_bin.push_back(clients[i]);
    clients.erase(i);
    break;//this line makes it work.
}
```

So problem is caused when for loop iterates after deleting something from clients.

**The question is :**

Why does it solve this problem automatically, without breaking out of the loop on the code compiled on windows but cannot solve it on centos 8 ?

Comment: collect each element you want to erase and after the for loop erase these elements from `clients`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> ```
> for (const auto& kv : clients) {
> ```

This iterates over the range using iterators. After the loop body is executed each time, the iterator is incremented.

> ```
> int i = kv.first;
> clients.erase(i);
> ```

This invalidates the current iterator. When the invalid iterator is incremented after the loop body, the behaviour of the program is undefined.

---

> ```
>  break;//this line makes it work.
> ```
>
> Why does it solve this problem

Because when you break out of the loop before the invalid iterator is incremented, there is no undefined behaviour.

Comment: thanks my friend. But I already understand that part. what I'm asking is , why does it work differently when I compile the code on windows using visual studio 2019 even if I dont use "break;" but doesn'T work on centos 8 using visual code and g++.

Comment: @uterian I already told you: The behaviour of the program is undefined.

Comment: so it's not like different compilers handles for loops differently but just "random" ?

Comment: @uterian It's undefined behaviour. It's not guaranteed to be random. Nothing about the behaviour of the program is guaranteed.

Comment: Excellent and patient confrontation with the concept of [UB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). Well done. This realization is a breakthrough realization any C++ programmer must have.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you only want to erase the **first** timed-out client, instead of **all** timed-out clients (which is more likely), then there is a bug in your code.

Is this what you intended?:

```
auto kv = clients.begin();
while (kv != clients.end()) {
    int elapsed_seconds = boost::chrono::duration_cast<boost::chrono::seconds>
                                     (timeNow - kv->second->lastUpdated).count();
    if (elapsed_seconds >= ServerData::SessionTimeoutSeconds) {
        trash_bin.push_back(*kv);
        kv = clients.erase(kv);
    }
    else
        ++kv;
}
```

Comment: Or use `std::erase_if`

Comment: @eerorika yes, if you have a C++ 20 compiler.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @eerorika. Also, your `break` statement breaks out of the loop. Without it, the loop continues executing after your `if` statement gets a `true` condition. That's a very different action. Is your loop intended to delete only one client at a time?

Comment: thanks you , but what I'm asking is not "why it gives error". I know the reason . But I don't undershand why it behaves differently on different platforms. Also , no , that loop shouldn't remove only 1 client at a time. That "break;" is a short term solution , I will replace the whole code if needed , later on.

Comment: There may be implementation differences that are significant. I suspect that your call to `erase()` may be invalidating an iterator that is then revisited. Implementation differences might make the difference between failing silently and crashing. I'm mentally grasping at straws here, but I'd investigate that possibility with a debugger.

Comment: The important thing to realize is that even on platforms where it "seemed to work", it may work for 10 years, and then suddenly decide to eat your puppy and fire the nuclear missile. [Or, more realistically, cause silent data corruption that you only notice after you overwrote your backups]